# How many calculations can a GPU do with a given amount of FLOPS?

Tags: glsl, shader, vulkan, compute-shader

I have the following shader rendering voxels using raycasting:

```
#version 460
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable
#pragma optionNV(unroll all)

layout(binding = 3, std140) uniform compVarsOb {
    float time;
    float phiA;
    float thetaA;
    vec3 camPos;
    float fov;
    int voxWidth;
    int voxHeight;
    int voxDepth;
} cvo;


layout(binding = 2, rgba8) uniform writeonly image2D img;

float hash3(vec2 xy){
    xy = mod(xy, .19);
    float h = dot(xy.yyx, vec3(.013, 27.15, 2027.3));
    h *= h;
    h *= fract(h);
    
    return fract(h);
}






//layout(binding = 4) uniform sampler3D voxels;


layout(binding = 4, std140) buffer vData{
    vec4 voxels[];
};


float greaterThan(float a, float b){
    float d =  a - b;
    return (1. + (d / abs(d)))/2.;
}

float lesserThan(float a, float b){
    float d =  a - b;
    return (1. - (d / abs(d)))/2.;
}

float withinBounds(ivec3 li){
    vec3 l = vec3(li);
    return greaterThan(l.x, 0.) * lesserThan(l.x, cvo.voxWidth) * greaterThan(l.y, 0.) * lesserThan(l.y, cvo.voxHeight) * greaterThan(l.z, 0.) * lesserThan(l.z, cvo.voxDepth);
}


vec4 quaternionMult(vec4 a, vec4 b){
    return vec4(a.x * b.x - dot(a.yzw, b.yzw), a.x*b.yzw + b.x*a.yzw + cross(a.yzw, b.yzw));
}


void main()
{
    vec2 iResolution = vec2(2560., 1440.);
    vec2 fragCoord = gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy;
    ivec2 fragI = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
    
    vec2 iMouse = vec2(.5);

    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;
    ivec2 uvI = ivec2(uv);
    
    vec2 muv = iMouse.xy / iResolution.xy;
    
    float iTime = cvo.time;
    
    vec3 col = vec3(0.);
    
    float screenRatio = iResolution.y / iResolution.x;
    
    //Setting up the ray directions and other information about the point and camera
    //##############################################################################
    
    
    //camera direction angles phi (xy plane) and theta (xz plane)
    float phi = cvo.phiA;//radians(360. * (1. - muv.x));
    float theta = cvo.thetaA;//radians(180. * (1. - muv.y));
    
    //get the camera direction as the basis for the rotation (each ray direction is a rotation of the camera direciton vector)
    //it is in quarternion form here so its a vec4 instead of a vec3
    vec4 camD = vec4(0., cos(phi) * sin(theta), sin(phi) * sin(theta), cos(theta));
    
    
    float rad90 = radians(90.);
    
    float fov = cvo.fov;
    
    float xAng = radians(fov * (.5 - uv.x));
    //replace "fov" with "(fov + (110. * pow(.5 - uv.x, 2.)))" below to add a counteractment to the fisheye lens effect
    //it basically counteracts the artifact with quaternions that happens when you rotate by a large angle on one axis then try to rotate on another axis perpendicular, it just rotates around it thus making the new direction lesser
    float yAng = radians(fov * screenRatio * (uv.y - .5));
    
    //get the axes that the quarternions should be based around (perpendicular to the camera plane or dv)
    vec3 xRotAxis = vec3(cos(phi) * sin(theta - rad90), sin(phi) * sin(theta - rad90), cos(theta - rad90));
    vec3 yRotAxis = cross(xRotAxis, camD.yzw);//vec3(cos(phi - rad90) * sin(theta), sin(phi - rad90) * sin(theta), cos(theta));
    
    //get the quarternions of the ray direction rotations
    vec4 xQuat = vec4(cos(xAng / 2.), xRotAxis * sin(xAng / 2.));
    vec4 yQuat = vec4(cos(yAng / 2.), yRotAxis * sin(yAng / 2.));
    
    
    
    //combine the rotations
    vec4 compQuat = quaternionMult(yQuat, xQuat);
    
    
    
    //get the conjugate of the compQuart
    vec4 conjComp = vec4(compQuat.x, -compQuat.yzw);

    
    //ray direction
    vec3 rayD = normalize(quaternionMult(quaternionMult(compQuat, camD), conjComp).yzw);
    
    
    
    
    //camera location
    vec3 cam = cvo.camPos;//vec3(cos(iTime), 0., 0.);
    
    
    //point location and radius
    //vec3 p = vec3(0., (5. * iTime) + 1., 0.);
    float pr = .00001;
    
    



    //############################################
    



    
    //hit = 1. means that nothing has been hit or everything has been completely transparent
    float hit = 1.;
    vec3 locf = vec3(0.);
    ivec3 loc = ivec3(0);
    int locI = 0;
    vec4 v = vec4(0.);

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        locf = vec3((i * rayD * .4) + cam);
        loc = ivec3(locf);
        //adjust loc for the buffer indexing
        locI = loc.x + loc.y * cvo.voxWidth + loc.z * cvo.voxWidth * cvo.voxHeight;

        //vec4 v = texelFetch(voxels, loc, 0);//;imageLoad(voxels, loc);//texelFetch(voxels, ivec3((i * rayD) + cam), 0);
        
        

        v = voxels[locI];// * withinBounds(loc);

        if(locf.x < 0. || locf.x > cvo.voxWidth || locf.y < 0. || locf.y > cvo.voxHeight || locf.z < 0. || locf.z > cvo.voxDepth){
            v = vec4(0.);
        }

        col += v.xyz * hit * v.w;

        hit -= v.w;

        if(hit <= 0.){
            //col = vec3(v.w / 5.);
            break;
        }
         
        
    }
    

    //col = imageLoad(voxels, ivec3(uvI, 1)).xyz;//texelFetch(voxels, ivec3(fragI / 10, 1), 0).xyz;
    //col = vec3(phi / radians(180.));
    
    //col = texture(iChannel0, uv).xyz;
    
    //col = voxels[(fragI.x / 10) + (fragI.y / 10) * cvo.voxWidth].xyz;

    //col = vec3(rayD.z);

    imageStore(img, fragI, vec4(col,1.0));
}
```

It produces this:
[image]
The problem is when I change the loop (end of main()) for the amount of voxels I want to iterate over to more than 2 (its at 20 right now), the fps absolutely tanks. Yet I feel that my GPU is capable of way more than 2 iterations of a not so demanding loop, so I'm not sure what is going on.

I am running on an RTX 2060 Super which [here](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-rtx-2060-super.c3441) is said to be capable of 7.81 * 10^12 FLOPS. If I'm understanding it correctly, this means that if I want to run a compute shader at 144 fps at 1440p, I would be allowed a total of (7.81 * 10^12)/(144 * 2560 * 1440) FLOPS in my shader. That comes out to about 14712 FLOPS in the compute shader which is **way** more than I have in my compute shader right now, yet my code only runs at an average of 30 fps when the loop is at 20 iterations. I can only get 144+ fps when I cut the loop down to 1 or 2 iterations (which at that point is basically like not having the loop at all). Are loops just horribly unoptimized for compute shaders? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: "Are loops just horribly unoptimized" Do you know what a non-uniform control flow is?

Comment: I didn't, I just looked at some stuff on it and from what I can gather quickly it seems like what you're telling me is that I shouldn't be using `voxels[locI]` as a buffer, but rather as a uniform buffer. the problem with this is that it won't let me access indices of `voxels` with a variable when its a uniform buffer.

Comment: My point is that if your loop has 20 iterations, then it obviously gets 20 times slower. But yea, you might also be memory bound by all the random memory access. You load 20x vec4 in pretty uncacheable way per invocation. So that's like 20*2560*1440*144*4*4 = 160 GBps of random nonsequential memory access.

Comment: Oh yes I believe you nailed the problem. My GPU has a Memory clock speed of about 14 GBps, which per iteration you showed it would be 8 GBps. My program loses framerate at and after 2 iterations which would be 16 GBps of memory access. No wonder 20 iterations absolutely kills it, its the memory not the computations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The flops GPU is capable of is usually calculated given perfect conditions with perfect code. That is, every computation is a Fused Multiply Add, is able to start right after the previous one with data already in cache/registers, and every single core is working. Achieving such conditions is the problem of writing code on GPUs.

GPUs normally create multiple threads per core in order to reduce penalty from having to wait for memory accesses. Caches are used to work with large bandwith usage, but they are relatively small and they require memory locality(data being stored physically close) for effective usage. Some GPUs have a separate texture cache, abusing which might be wise. Drivers also try to store textures and images in an efficient way, at least by making pixels close by - also close in memory, but potentially using some special hardware.

In compute shaders, threads are created in large blocks and then assigned to Compute Units (terminology differs between vendors, basically sort of a meta-core, with own cache and a bunch of cores). The size of block a is defined in shader with `layout(local_size_x = X​, local_size_y = Y​, local_size_z = Z​) in;`, where total number of threads equals to the multiple of the dimensions. Threads within a block can communicate with `shared` variables (they are usually stored within same space as l1 cache) and synchronise with `barrier()` and alike. GPUs have multiple compute units, and to make them work multiple blocks should be launched(the values in `vkCmdDispatch()` are the number of groups launched).

Threads are also implicitly grouped in SIMD-like groups (nVidia calls it SIMT - single instruction multiple threads). Every thread in one such group performs the same instruction(but there are some differences with newer nVidia cards). **In case where an `if()` or `for()`, `while()`, etc. makes only some threads execute a portion of code, part of cores are disabled, potentially wasting performance.** Usually they have size of 32 or 64(AMD), so thread blocks should be created as a multiple of that number. Some functionalities of such groups are exposed with [subgroup extensions](https://www.khronos.org/blog/vulkan-subgroup-tutorial).

---

Since you are working with voxels, i'd imagine that using 3D textures or images instead of a buffer may be good for caches. Figuring out how to make threads cooperate and make use of the fast shared memory should also be a good idea.